# Rounding numbers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, formatting, rounding

I'm trying to do some number rounding and conversion to a string to enhance the output in an Objective-C program.

I have a float value that I'd like to round to the nearest .5 and then use it to set the text on a label.

For example:

1.4 would be a string of: 1.5

1.2 would be a string of: 1

0.2 would be a string of: 0

I've spent a while looking on Google for an answer but, being a noob with Objective-C, I'm not sure what to search for! So, I'd really appreciate a pointer in the right direction!

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: Except for adding the value to a label (which he's declaring as his intent and not actually asking about) his question has nothing to do with Cocoa and everything to do with Obj-C

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers everyone, I've managed to come up with a solution:

```
float roundedValue = round(2.0f * number) / 2.0f;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundedValue]];
[formatter release];
```

The above works for the test cases I threw at it, but if anyone knows a better way to do this I'd be interested to hear it!

Comment: If this is being output to a text field, you can just attach the formatter to the field.

Answer (score 40):

```
float floatVal = 1.23456;
```

**Rounding**

```
int roundedVal = lroundf(floatVal); 

NSLog(@"%d",roundedVal);
```

**Rounding Up**

```
int roundedUpVal = ceil(floatVal); 

NSLog(@"%d",roundedUpVal);
```

**Rounding Down**

```
int roundedDownVal = floor(floatVal);

NSLog(@"%d",roundedDownVal);
```

Answer (score 33):

```
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", round(2.0f * number) / 2.0f];
```

Answer (score 25):

Use lroundf() to round a float to integer and then convert the integer to a string.

Comment: This seems a bit confusing, so I clarify. `lroundf()` rounds a float to a whole number and gives it back as long integer (to convert it to a string you can use `stringWithFormat:`).

Answer (score 11):

```
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",lroundf(number)];
```

Comment: It is good to explain how your answer works.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend looking into using [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368).

Answer (score 6):

a simple way:

```
float theFloat = 1.23456;
int rounded = roundf(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",rounded);
int roundedUp = ceil(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedUp);
int roundedDown = floor(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedDown);
// Note: int can be replaced by float
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *intNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)floatNumber];
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Technique worked for me in a financial application.

```
 NSString *dd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",monthlyPaymentCalculated];

        monthlyPaymentCalculated=[dd doubleValue];

self.monthlyPaymentCritical=monthlyPaymentCalculated;
```

what is did is first is rounded it with %0.2f and stored it in NSString then i simply converted it again into double and result was good for my calculation.

Answer (score 2):

With these functions you can round to any value.. If you use p=2, you get even numbers.

```
float RoundTo(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int((x+(1/(y+y)))*y)/y;
}

float RoundUp(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int((x+(1/y))*y)/y;
}

float RoundDown(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int(x*y)/y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be able to round to a specific digit (not necessarily to whole integers). I made a `NSNumber` category (based off [Ash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753928/347339)) and added the following method to it:

```
- (NSString *)stringByRounding:(NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode)roundingMode
      toPositionRightOfDecimal:(NSUInteger)position
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:position];
    [formatter setRoundingMode:roundingMode];
    NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:self];
    return numberString;
}
```

Which allows me to use it like so:

```
[aNumber stringByRounding:NSNumberFormatterRoundUp toPositionRightOfDecimal:2];
```

I can use it to round to integers by passing in `0` as the second parameter:

```
[aNumber stringByRounding:NSNumberFormatterRoundPlain toPositionRightOfDecimal:0];
```