# 0.7 is not less than 0.7 but wrong result gets printed

Tags: c, comparison

Here 'a' should get printed as 0.7 < 0.7 is false, but 'c' is printed.

```C
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  float a=0.7;
  if(a<0.7)
    printf("c");
  else
    printf("a");
}
```

Comment: `int main(void)`, not `void main()`.

Comment: a is a float while 0.7 is a double.

Comment: Try `printf("float a %0.20e 0.7 %0.20e\n", a, 0.7);` to see what is really being compared.  Then think about the more limiting precision of a `float` vs. `double`.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef and that is duplicate already. Thus this question is grand-duplicate :)

Comment: Better answers in [Floating point comparison `a != 0.7`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883306/floating-point-comparison-a-0-7)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand floating point numbers. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829067/how-can-i-round-a-float-value-to-2-post-decimal-positions).

One thing you can do is think "Well, it will never be *exactly* 0.7, so maybe I can't judge for sure, but I can get *close*...

Then, you pick a granularity, say, one millionth. You can try comparing the **integer** rounded result of `ie6 * a` to the **integer** rounded result of `1e6 * 0.7` to see not so much "is `a < 0.7`?", but "is `a` reasonably, close-enough, less than `0.7`?"

Or, just compare to the same type. As said in the comments, maybe `0.7` is not a `float` literal but a `double` literal. Ensure it's a `float` literal to be sure, and `'a'` is printed.

```
void main()
{
  float a=0.7;
  if(a<0.7f)
    printf("c");
  else
    printf("a");
}
```