# How do I round off to the nearest .05 or .10 in C?

Tags: c

I have tried using the ceil function but it rounds it to the nearest integer. My program aims to round a price of a subscription off to the nearest 0.05, for example 19.83 to 19.85, or nearest 0.1, for example 19.88 to 19.90

How would I go about this?

Comment: You would do some lateral thinking. Note that the specific value `0.1` cannot be represented exactly with the standard types `double` and `float` in in most implementations of C.

Comment: Great explanation for the problems occuring when you have to multiply and re-divide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829067/how-can-i-round-a-float-value-to-2-post-decimal-positions

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand because I'm rather new in C, could you explain further?

Comment: (In case that was directed to me) You cannot represent `0.1` *exactly* in a `double` or `float`, just as you cannot represent `1/3` *exactly* in decimal notation.

Comment: seems like searching for "round to multiple" yields usable code like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407012/c-rounding-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-a-number

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by something, round, and then re-divide.

Something is left as an exercise (hint : it is related to the "nearest").

Answer (score 0):

For your example:

```
Double ex = 19.88;
Double ex2;
Double ex3;

ex2 = ex * 100;

If ( ex2 % 50  >= 25 )
{
ex2 = ex2 + 50 - ( ex2 % 50 );  // Rounding up
}
Else
{
ex2 = ex2 - ( ex2 % 50);   // rounding down
}

ex = ex2 / 100;
```

For further learning:

By multiplying ex by 100, you ensure that its a whole number. Now, if you do number % (modulo) anything, it will return whats left after you divide through anything. ex2 % 50 essentially does this. Now its only a case of properly rounding up or down.

Comment: thank you, but is it possible to achieve what I want with the ceil function or is that limited to only rounding numbers off to the nearest integer?

Comment: `ceil(Double f)` will only round up. to the next integer value. So 19.88 becomes 20.

Comment: okay, thank you so much!

Comment: @ninjedi If you are interested in uses for `ceil(Double f)` have a read here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_ceil.htm