# How to round Decimal values in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

This may be a easy question but i am not able to find the logic.

I am getting the values like this

12.010000
   12.526000
   12.000000
   12.500000

If i get the value 12.010000 I have to display 12.01

If i get the value 12.526000 I have to display 12.526

If i get the value 12.000000 I have to display 12

If i get the value 12.500000 I have to display 12.5

Can any one help me out please

Thank You

Comment: What are those values? `float`? NSNumber? NSDecimalNumber? What do you mean by "display"? Convert to NSString? Print to console? NSLog?

Comment: Actually I am getting it as NSString I can convert them in to float. Display means I have to display those values in view by converting them in to nsstring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", 12.010000]
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", 12.526000]
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", 12.000000]
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", 12.500000]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
float roundedValue = 45.964;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:roundedValue]];

NSLog(numberString);
[formatter release];
```

Some modification you may need-

```
// You can specify that how many floating digit you want as below 
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:4];//2];

// You can also round down by changing this line 
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];//NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
```

Reference: A query on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752817/rounding-numbers-in-objective-c)

Comment: Hi Sadat thanks for your answer. I tried this code but When i am passing the float value 12.526000, I'm getting the value 12.57 in the "NSString *numberString", but I have to get 12.526 in string value, same as for 12.010000 i am getting 12.02 but i have to get 12.01.

Thank You

Comment: Change in this line: [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
place 3 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously taskinoor's solution is the best, but you mentioned you couldn't find the logic to solve it... so here's the logic. You basically loop through the characters in reverse order looking for either a non-zero or period character, and then create a substring based on where you find either character.

```
-(NSString*)chopEndingZeros:(NSString*)string {
    NSString* chopped = nil;
    NSInteger i;
    for (i=[string length]-1; i>=0; i--) {
        NSString* a = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        if ([a isEqualToString:@"."]) {
            chopped = [string substringToIndex:i];
            break;
        } else if (![a isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            chopped = [string substringToIndex:i+1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return chopped;
}
```