# How to round off Float values?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Rounding numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752817/rounding-numbers-in-objective-c)

In Objective-c How to round off Float values?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

In addition to the other answers:

```
float theFloat = 1.23456;
int rounded = roundf(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",rounded);
int roundedUp = ceil(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedUp);
int roundedDown = floor(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedDown);
// Note: int can be replaced by float
```

For rounding to specific decimals, see the question mentioned by Alex Kazaev.

Comment: You should use `roundf` instead of `lroundf` for casting to `int` without warning. I could not edit your post because of the minimum character change limit for edit.

Answer (score 18):

The function `lroundf()` will do it:

```
float a=20.49;
int myInt = lroundf(a);
```

Comment: what if the value of a is more than 20.5 ?

Comment: no. lroundf(a) gives u like if value is 20.75 then it become 21 and if value is 20.45 then it become 20... means more than 20.5 then it will become 21 else 20. :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert to int and then convert back to float.

```
CGFloat *myFloat = 100.765;
NSInteger *myInteger = myFloat;
CGFloat *newFloat = myInteger;
```

This will work

Comment: That's truncation (floor/ceil) not rounding.