# How to round of the value?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-c: How to round off Float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594116/objective-c-how-to-round-off-float-values)

I wanted to roundoff the float value from 42.56789 to 42.6. Can any one help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions in c namely **floor** and **ceil** to roundoff the float values.

Refer [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

Comment: Note that directly using those functions will not produce the rounding expected by the OP.

Comment: How comes you give an answer even though the asker is not user692270? Are you growing up?

Answer (score 0):

```
float value=42.56789;
NSString *roundedValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f",value];
NSLog(@"%@",roundedValue);
```

It prints 43 on console.

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 42.56789;

    f *= 10.0f;

    f = ceilf(f);

    f /= 10.0f;

    NSLog(@"%.02f",f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it manually .

```
float val=42.567890// float gives 6 decimal places
int x=(int) val;
float f=val-(int)val;
int o=(int) f*10;
float round=x+o/10+(f-(o/10))*1000)/50;
```

Comment: you should not type cast a float value into int value because float has a higher rage then int.