# round number 105 or 95 to 100 in objective c

Tags: objective-c, rounding

I have integer value, and need to round it, how to do that?

105 will be 110
103 will be 100

so classical rounding for decimals? thank you!

Comment: round(value/10)*10 doesnt work?

Comment: @Chad: There are solutions that don't need floating point, but if you do want to use floating point you need to make either sure that `value` is already a float or divide by `10.0`, otherwise you're doing an integer divide which is then casted to float.

Answer (score 4):

One more for you:

```
int originalNumber = 95; // or whatever
int roundedNumber = 10 * ((originalNumber + 5)/10);
```

Integer division always truncates in C, so e.g. 3/4 = 0, 4/4 = 1.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the exact Objective-C syntax, byt general programming question. C-style:

```
int c = 105;
if (c % 10 >= 5) {
    c += 10;
}
c -= c % 10;
```

No floating point calculations required.

Comment: Or, maybe c = 10 * ((c + 5)/10); ? If you wanted to avoid conditionals.

Comment: @Tommy: You should provide that as an answer, because it's Yet Another Way of solving this problem :-) You're taking advantage of the fact that an integer division "loses information".

Comment: shame on me :)))) this = 10 * ((c + 5)/10) is great! and working! :) thank you and thank all! :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this:

```
rounded = (value + 5) - ((value + 5) % 10);
```

Or slightly modified:

```
rounded = value + 5;
rounded -= rounded % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: [Rounding numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752817/rounding-numbers-in-objective-c)

You could support floats or express your ints as floats (105.0).

Comment: Note that to achieve what the poster wants by using floats, you would need to do `round(value / 10.0) * 10.0`.