# Rounding float number upto two decimal places

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to round a floating value upto two decimal places. I am using objective-c

e.g 1.47567 should be like this , 1.47 .. Please help

Thnx .

Comment: That's not "rounding", it's truncation. Since the third digit is `5`, rounding would be `1.48`. Which one would you like to do?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560517/make-a-float-only-show-two-decimal-places

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752817/rounding-numbers-in-objective-c duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    float num = 1.47567;
    num *= 100;
    if(num >= 0) num += 0.5; else num -= 0.5;
    long round = num;
    num = round;
    num /= 100;
    NSLog(@"%.2f",num);
```

Comment: I don't have to re-format it , I want that if after rounding i write NSLog(@"%f",num); then i should get 1.47  . .

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(self.speed)];
```

Comment: I would always use NSNumberFormatter, since it's easier this way to re-use formats. Use NSNumberFormatterRoundDown to avoid rounding.
Also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264109/how-to-avoid-rounding-off-in-nsnumberformatter

Answer (score 0):

```
double value = 1.47567;
double roundedValue = round(value * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Of course you can use a named constant in place of 100.0. This is just a demo.

Comment: By applying NSLog(@"Rounded value is :%f",roundedValue);
It prints 1.480000 ..  but i want that rounded value should have 1.47 or lets say 1.48 .

Comment: In the comment @jimpic's answer you said you did not want to print it, but to use it. So, when you use it, what do you think is the difference between 1.48 and 1.480000?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(self.speed)];

float numTwoDecimalDigits = atof([formattedNumber UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSLog(@"%.2f", 1.47567);
```

would round to two decimal places. If you want to "cut", there are different options. For example:

```
NSLog(@"%.2f", floor(1.47567 * 100) / 100);
```

Comment: I am not about to print the value. But i have to use it .
All I want that after being round , my variable should contain like 1.45. .