# How to avoid rounding off in NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, trim, nsnumberformatter, decimal

I am trying to have a number string with maximum 2 decimals precision, while rest decimals just trimmed off instead of rounding them up. For example:

`I have: 123456.9964`

`I want: 123456.99 -> Just want to trim rest of the decimal places`

What I have tried is:

```cs
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 123456.9964]];
 NSLog(@"%@", numberAsString);
```

There is nothing to set rounding mode as "none". What else can I do to maintain Decimal style formatting along with trimmed decimal digits? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
// optional - [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
NSNumber *num = @(123456.9964);
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:num];
NSLog(@"%@", numberAsString);
```

The output is: 123,456.99

Part of your problem is the use of `numberWithFloat:` instead of `numberWithDouble:`. Your number has too many digits for `float`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 123456.9964]];
NSLog(@"%@", numberAsString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
```

Use this code.

Comment: Not working. I am getting output as: 123457 while I want 123456.99

Comment: @AnumAmin What is you also specify minimum fraction digits of 2?

Comment: @maddy if I specify min fractions as 2 (which is my requirement), I still get 123457.00

Answer (score -1):

you can also just use round() and then convert it into a string afterward

```
var y = round(100 * 123456.8864) / 100

var x:String = String(format:"%.2f", y)
println("x: \(x)")
```

would print x: 123456.89, rounding the 8 to a 9.

Comment: whoops! forgot about the no rounding part.