# Unexpected value printed when using %.1f

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point

I'm trying to display floats to just one decimal point. I'm getting unexpected results as follows:

Code:

```
float a = 1.25;
float b = 1.35;

NSLog(@"1.25 -> %.1f\n1.35 -> %.1f",a,b);
```

Output:

> 1.25 -> 1.2
>
> 1.35 -> 1.4

Expected output, either:

> 1.25 -> 1.3
>
> 1.35 -> 1.4

or:

> 1.25 -> 1.2
>
> 1.35 -> 1.3

Is this simply due to the internal conversion between binary and decimal? If so, how do I get the expected behaviour?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.

edit: Okay, thanks to TonyK and H2CO3 it's due to the binary representation of decimals.

```
float a = 1.25;
float b = 1.35;
NSLog(@"1.25 -> %.30f\n1.35 -> %.30f",a,b);
```

> 1.25 -> 1.250000000000000000000000000000
>
> 1.35 -> 1.350000000000000088817841970013

Lots of good info, but as far as I can see no one has approached the second question: How do I get the expected behaviour?

[Rounding numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752817/rounding-numbers-in-objective-c) is a quite different question.

Comment: This relates to all the C languages, not just Objective C. What you get depends on the system, 1.25 could be printed as 1.2 or 1.3.

Answer (score 5):

1.35 is 27/20, which in binary is

```
1.01 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110....
```

A `float` has a 23-bit mantissa on most systems (not counting the implied leading 1.), so this gets rounded up to

```
1.01 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 1
```

(because 0110 is unambiguously greater than half of 1000). So it's strictly greater than 1.35 by the time `printf` sees it. Hence 1.4.

As for 1.25, this is exactly representable in binary as

```
1.01
```

So `printf` sees its exact value. But how should it round 1.25? We were taught in school to round 5 up to 10. But most modern systems use a default rounding mode called "round to even" at the hardware level, because it lessens the effect of cumulative rounding errors. This means that when a number is exactly between the two nearest candidates for rounding, it gets rounded to the even candidate.

So it seems that `print` is using "round to even" for decimal output! I checked this hypothesis at [this ideone link](http://ideone.com/27FMnL), and indeed 1.75 gets rounded up, to 1.8. This is a surprise to me, but not a huge one.

Comment: Thanks for making an effort digging through the full binary representation. +1.

Answer (score 2):

That's because floating-point numbers aren't exact. `%.1f` prints the number **rounded** to one decimal place, it seems, however, that `1.35` can't be exactly represented as 1.2500000, instead it's a slightly smaller number that can be.

Read about this behavior here: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: 1.25 = 5/4 can be represented exactly, because 4 is a power of 2. It's 1.35 = 27/20 that can't be represented exactly.

Comment: @TonyK Right, but then why is it truncated instead of rounded?

Comment: Okay, thank you TonyK and H2CO3. You might interested in my edit which shows the behaviour of %.30f as demonstration. What's the usual way of working around this to get consistent behaviour?