# Round an NSString containing a decimal to two decimal digits

Tags: ios, decimal

Given the NSString "1.625", I want to round this to "1.63".
How in the world do I do that?

This is what i have now:

```
NSString *rateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [@"1.63" doubleValue]];
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
item.rate = [f numberFromString:rateString];;
```

However, doubleValue converts 1.625 to 1.6249999999
So when I round it to two decimal digits with @"%.2f", I end up with 1.62!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounding numbers in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752817/rounding-numbers-in-objective-c)

Comment: Look into using `NSDecimalNumber` instead of using `double`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna round to the nearest hundredths, multiply by 100, increment by .5 and divide by 100. Then get the floor of that value.

```
double rate = [@"1.625" doubleValue];
double roundedNumber = floor(rate * 100 + 0.5) / 100;

NSString *rateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", roundedNumber];
NSLog(@"rate: %@", rateString);
```

Running this then outputting the result:

```
2015-01-13 15:41:08.702 Sandbox[22027:883332] rate: 1.63
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need high precision what you really need is `NSDecimalNumber`class maybe coupled with `NSDecimalNumberHandler` if don't need to configure all details, or `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` if need absolute control. This is the quickest solution to keep 2 decimal digits (the 'scale' value in handler init):

```
NSDecimalNumberHandler *handler = [[NSDecimalNumberHandler alloc]initWithRoundingMode:NSRoundBankers
                                                                                scale:2
                                                                     raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                                      raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                                                     raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                                                  raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

[NSDecimalNumber setDefaultBehavior:handler];

NSString *string = @"1.63";
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string];
```

NSDecimalNumber docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html

NSDecimalNumberHandler docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumberHandler_Class/index.html

NSDecimalNumberBehaviors docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/index.html